# How to make design for horizontal fixed menu as image below

Tags: css, css-position, menubar

**I need to make horizontal fixed menu as image below:**

[menu i need to design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzvqK.jpg)

I try to make it

but remaining some point modification to be same as image above

points remaining(meaning i need to add these points to fiddle)

1 - add | between words

2 - also black rectangle of menu not same size as image above .

my fiddle as below(what I try it)

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedsa/xkabohyw/

```
 ul {
        border-top: 4px solid red;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
        top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
        width: 100%; /* Full width */

    }

    li {
        float: right;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
<ul>
        <li><a href="#home">الرئيسيه</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">نبذه عن</a><i>|</i></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a></li>
    </ul>
```

so that

**How to add these points to fiddle if possible please?**

Comment: is it what you need?: https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/kk05kabq/

Comment: remaining one point if possible. the point remaining i need to make small high to rectangle black color of menu

Comment: I need the same size of black color of menu above

Comment: that i write in post image

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. You can use border or background image. But this is a solution with HTML and CSS [here is update code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJZNmr)

HTML

```
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">الرئيسيه</a></li>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <li><a href="#news">نبذه عن</a><i>|</i></li>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */

}

li {
    float: right;

    line-height:1px;

}
span {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 0;
     height: 1em;
     border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
     margin-top:8px;
     float: right;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;


}
```